# QGIS Line between two points based on topography

Tags: qgis, topography

Is it possible in QGIS to draw a line between two points and take the topography into account? For Example when there's a mountain or a lake between the two points, the line goes around that mountain or lake

Comment: What are the rules ? The topography's height must be the same for all the line ? If there is no solution, what result do you expect ? Have you a MNT in entry data ?

Comment: [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168463/128665) refers to a GRASS solution using rasters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-cost_routing